# Google maps API not "finding" addresses even though they work normally on the web

Tags: python, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

Trying to write a python script that uses Google Distance Matrix API to calculated the distance to a single location. For some reason it works for some addresses and not others and I can't figure out why that is.

The code I used was a modified version of this: https://gist.github.com/olliefr/407c64413f61bd14e7af62fada6df866

Where I simply changed it so it takes in a list on the form (Lines 50/51):

```
['Nordmarksvägen 15', 'Häggvägen 25B', 'Nordenskiöldsgatan 78', 'Oskarsvägen 
7B', 'Norrviksvägen 22A']
```

and
 returns a distance between each entry to my point.
Here we can clearly see that some entries from my origins array are not working?

Here is the print of my "results array" where we clearly see that 3 out of the 5 entries didn't work.

```
 to Kungstensgatan 6, 114 25 Stockholm, Sweden: status = NOT_FOUND
 to Kungstensgatan 6, 114 25 Stockholm, Sweden: status = NOT_FOUND
 to Kungstensgatan 6, 114 25 Stockholm, Sweden: status = NOT_FOUND
['13.5 km Nordmarksvägen 15, 123 72 Farsta, Sweden', '3.5 km 
Nordenskiöldsgatan 78, 115 21 Stockholm, Sweden']
```

Going to add the full code here just in case there is any confusion:

```
import json
import requests
import sys
# Google Distance Matrix Python Demo
# ==================================
#
# H


distances = []
org = []

if __name__ == '__main__':

# The API key must be provided on the command line, abort otherwise. 
api_key = 'Just gonna keeps this away for now'


# Google Distance Matrix base URL to which all other parameters are attached
base_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?'

# Google Distance Matrix domain-specific terms: origins and destinations
origins = ['Nordmarksvägen 15', 'Häggvägen 25B', 'Nordenskiöldsgatan 78', 'Oskarsvägen 7B', 'Norrviksvägen 22A']
destinations = ['Kungstensgatan 6']

# Prepare the request details for the assembly into a request URL
payload = {
    'origins' : '|'.join(origins),
    'destinations' : '|'.join(destinations), 
    'mode' : 'walking',
    'api_key' : api_key
}

# Assemble the URL and query the web service
r = requests.get(base_url, params = payload)

# Check the HTTP status code returned by the server. Only process the response, 
# if the status code is 200 (OK in HTTP terms).
if r.status_code != 200:
    print('HTTP status code {} received, program terminated.'.format(r.status_code))
else:
    try:
        # Try/catch block should capture the problems when loading JSON data, 
        # such as when JSON is broken. It won't, however, help much if JSON format
        # for this service has changed -- in that case, the dictionaries json.loads() produces
        # may not have some of the fields queried later. In a production system, some sort
        # of verification of JSON file structure is required before processing it. In XML
        # this role is performed by XML Schema.
        x = json.loads(r.text)

        # Now you can do as you please with the data structure stored in x.
        # Here, we print it as a Cartesian product.
        for isrc, src in enumerate(x['origin_addresses']):
            for idst, dst in enumerate(x['destination_addresses']):
                row = x['rows'][isrc]
                cell = row['elements'][idst]
                if cell['status'] == 'OK':
                    distances.append(cell['distance']['text'] +" "+ src)

                else:
                    print('{} to {}: status = {}'.format(src, dst, cell['status']))
        print(distances)

    except ValueError:
        print('Error while parsing JSON response, program terminated.')
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't actually figure out the exact cause but I found that it starts working if you provide additional information such as state and country and not just the address!

For example:

```
origins = ['Nordmarksvägen 15']
```

should be written

```
origins = ['Nordmarksvägen 15, State, Country' ]
```

This solved the issue in my case and now all entries are working!